# View Not Showing Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following view in `app/views/posts/index.html.erb`:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<%= post.user %> is listening to <%= post.song %> by <%= post.artist %> from <%= post.album %>

<% end %>
```

And the corresponding controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.find(:all)   
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])  
  end 

  def new
    @post = Post.new           
  end

  def create                   
    @post = Post.new(params[:posts])
    if @post.save              
      redirect_to action: "index"     
    else                       
      @posts = Post.find(:all) 
      render action: 'new'     
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is, when I create a record with the song attribute being "The Sound of Settling", the artist attribute being "Death Cab for Cutie", and the album atrribute being "Transatlanticism", nothing shows up when I render the index view.

Comment: Are you sure the post is being created successfully?  Can you post the snippet from your development.log file showing the output when you are creating the Post?

Comment: Your `index` code looks like it can't go wrong.  I'd suspect that your form is off somehow.  (Hey, how come you're using `params[:posts]` in your `create` action?)

Comment: @cbascom `(0.1ms)  begin transaction  SQL (144.9ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("album", "artist", "created_at", "song", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["album", nil], ["artist", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 25 Dec 2012 15:28:49 UTC +00:00], ["song", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 25 Dec 2012 15:28:49 UTC +00:00]`

Comment: Notice all values are nil? As bdares said :posts is incorrect, should be :post in the create action

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm such an idiot sometimes.

Comment: It happens to all of us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @house9 and @bdares said, I had `:posts` in my `create` action when it should have been `:post`.

Answer (score 1):

For situations like this, the [command line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) is invaluable.

```
$ rails console
```

Then play around, insert some data, fetch some. Start off with what goes wrong here:

```
> @posts = Post.find(:all)
> pp @posts
```

No results? there are no Posts, at all. Probably because of a problem on insertation:

```
> @post = Post.new({:user => 1, :song => "give it up", :artist => "rick", :album => "youtube greatest hits"})
> @post.valid?
> pp @post.errors
> @post.save!
```

It allows you to eliminate most problems beforehand.